# nginx configuration issue: sub directory as root directory not working

Tags: nginx

I have a created a subdomain http://lms.rguktn.ac.in. I am pointing the subdomain to a public IP. I want /var/www/html/lms to load when the site http://lms.rguktn.ac.in is accessed. But when I try to access the link lms.rguktn.ac.in it is loading from /var/www/html instead of the /var/www/html/lms folder. What am I missing? Here is the nginx config file lms.conf, I am using:

```
#lms.conf

server {
#listen 80;
#server_name lms.rguktn.ac.in;    

location / {
    root /var/www/html/lms;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    proxy_pass http://117.254.89.189;
    proxy_set_header Host lms.rguktn.ac.in;

# lms rewrite rules
rewrite ^/(.*.php)(/)(.*)$ /$1?file=/$3 last;
}

   # php parsing
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
 }

}
```

Comment: Please show clearly what you are looking for in the question. What is the exact filesystem path you want to show when visiting the `http://lms.rguktn.ac.in` URL? Please also add other directory - URL mappings if they differ from the basic pattern. Add the information to the question itself.

Comment: The question is still unclear. Why don't you just use "root /var/www/html/lms"?

Comment: Yea. I tried to improve the question now. I tried that too but it's not working. It's always loading from /var/www/html but not /var/www/html/lms

Comment: Of course it loads from `/var/www/html`. That is what you specifically asked it to do in the configuration. If you want it to use another directory, you need to change it!

Comment: Oops..my mistake. It's actually in the configuration /var/www/html/lms that is not working

Comment: `proxy_pass http://117.254.89.189;` passes the request to the default vhost that in turn displays the default HTML file. You may need to remove all the lines related to proxy and then move the `root` about all `location` blocks.

Comment: No effect even I remove those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to write root /var/ww**w**/html; but have root /var/ww/html; in your config. According to your current config /lms is relative to /var/ww/html/lms but if the directory is in /var/www/html it won't work.

Comment: yeah... the directory path is /var/www/html/lms